# Error Azure bot service generating APP ID & password

Tags: azure, bots, app-id

I am trying to create a bot service using Microsoft Azure, however, when I click the button to generate an APP ID and password I receive the following error "There's a temporary problem with the service. Please try again. If you continue to get this message, try again later.". Can anyone help?

Comment: You basically need to try again later since there's a temporary problem with the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the the issue persists for 5 days already, which makes me think it may be sth else.

Comment: Why don't you contact their support?

Comment: Thanks, but I have a trial account, and for technical support I have to upgrade to a paid plan. I don't find anywhere whether the free trial may be the issue, but theoretically it shouldn't since I use the budget allocated to the trial version...

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. In order to generate an Microsoft App ID and Password we need to have an Microsoft account. After creating an Microsoft email id I was able to generate the App ID and Password without any errors.